A little gap under <a> inside of <li> in a navbar
So currently I'm making a navbar as a new programmer and I got a problem there are little gaps under the  when my cursor hover over it.
White gap under user
I'm expecting the hover background colour to fill up the height without any gap left.




nav {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-self: center;
}

nav li {
  float: right;
  margin: 0;
}

nav>ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

nav>ul>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  padding: 15px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  transition: .0s;
  height: 100%;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: rgb(255, 178, 54);
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-SnH5WK+bZxgPHs44uWIX+LLJAJ9/2PkPKZ5QiAj6Ta86w+fsb2TkcmfRyVX3pBnMFcV7oQPJkl9QevSCWr3W6A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<header class="header">
  <?php session_start(); ?>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <?php if (isset($_SESSION['status']) && $_SESSION['status'] == "login") { ?>
      <li><a class="roboto-medium" href="#">STORE</a></li>
      <li><a class="roboto-medium" href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
      <li><a class="roboto-medium" href="#">HOME</a></li>
      <?php } else { ?>
      <li>
        <a class="fa fa-user" href="#"></a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="roboto-medium" href="#">REGISTER</a></li>
      <?php } ?>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>




Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Try adding padding: 0; to your nav li{}.

You can always use browser's Developer Console to check where does the "gap" come from.

Set ul, li, a to height:100%
nav li {
  float: right;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

nav > ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

nav > ul > li > a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  padding: 15px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
}




nav {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

nav li {
  margin: 0;
}

nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  padding: 0 15px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  transition: background-color 0.3s;
}

nav li a:hover {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: rgb(255, 178, 54);
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-SnH5WK+bZxgPHs44uWIX+LLJAJ9/2PkPKZ5QiAj6Ta86w+fsb2TkcmfRyVX3pBnMFcV7oQPJkl9QevSCWr3W6A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<header class="header">
  <?php session_start(); ?>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <?php if (isset($_SESSION['status']) && $_SESSION['status'] == "login") { ?>
      <li><a class="roboto-medium" href="#">STORE</a></li>
      <li><a class="roboto-medium" href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
      <li><a class="roboto-medium" href="#">HOME</a></li>
      <?php } else { ?>
      <li>
        <a class="fa fa-user" href="#"></a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="roboto-medium" href="#">REGISTER</a></li>
      <?php } ?>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>



Try this!
nav styling: Added display: flex and align-items: center to ensure items are vertically centered.
nav ul styling: Used display: flex for proper horizontal alignment without gaps.
nav li a styling:
Set display: flex and align-items: center to vertically center the content inside the  element.
Adjusted padding to 0 15px to ensure no extra space at the top and bottom.
Set height: 50px and line-height: 50px to make sure the  element fills the height of the navbar.

Your CSS makes the icon align top

updated the nav li and nav li a
--------//code//-------->
nav li {
margin: 0;
display: flex; /* Add flex display /
align-items: center; / Vertically center the items */
}
nav li a {
text-decoration: none;
color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
padding: 15px;
display: inline-flex; /* Use inline-flex to preserve the icon size /
align-items: center; / Vertically center the content */
transition: background-color 0.3s;
}
